# Wix - how to remotely login to external sites

Tags: javascript, node.js, wix, velo

I have a Wix website and a customer portal on another website.

The consumer will log on to my website and go directly to the customer portal without seeing the second login screen. But through the backend the consumer will log in to my website, the information that is placed in the "login and password" will be copied to the second login screen in invisible mode and then it will return to the customer portal in visible mode

I would like to know how I could make this communication invisible.
I started seeing libraries like Fetch and Express. I was only able to use it to collect data from other websites, but I was not able to post data from my website to the customer portal.

[customer portal link](https://app.sisloc.com.br/Portal/Login.aspx)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cm9Sk.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This is a very vague question, so could you give us some specifics about the customer portal. Do you know how it accepts data (POST/GET/other means)? When you say it redirects the head page, what does this mean exactly?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: ok, i edited the question. I think it was a little clearer that way

Answer (score -1):

What you are looking for is third-party authentification with Velo. You have to use the following API to generate a session's token: [generate session token](https://www.wix.com/velo/reference/wix-users-backend/generatesessiontoken).

Then you need to use that token to log the user [apply session token](https://www.wix.com/velo/reference/wix-users/applysessiontoken)